# md5.h File Not Found error Xcode 7 for Mac application

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I am trying to use the md5 module from the openSSL library. So in one of my header I included the openssl library by including it like this:

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

However Xcode is giving me the message md5.h file not found. I went into my /usr/include and confirmed that openssl/md5.h was present.

Here are the things that I have tried to solve the issue:

- I cleaned my project
- Made sure to include the libcrypto.dylib in the framework/library
  section
- I have included the /usr/include/ in the User Header search path and Header   search path within the build settings and have set it to recursively search sub directories

I am currently running OS X 10.10.5 and my Xcode version is 7.0.1

Comment: Consider using Common Crypto, it is part of the Apple supplied Security.framework. It is very fast 3.644 mSec for 1,000,000 bytes on an iPhone 6s. It is also FIPS-140-2 validated. Generally only a few lines of code. Also if possible consider SHA-256, MD5 is not suitable for new work.

Comment: Unfortunately the project that I am working on, I have inherited the code from previous developers and trying to rework a lot of their existing code is not a feasible solution.

Comment: Ah, another day, another successful attack! I love reading about the successful exploits and this is exactly how so many start. Companies keep putting off security updates until they becone a Target. I just ran timings on Common Crypto MD5, in the last four years the speed on an iPhone increased 6x. I can do 250K MD5 typical password hashes a second on an iPhone6s so I could run through 250K potential passwords in a second. Not so secure. SHA-256 is suitable for file hashes, etc but not passwords, for that there is PBKDF2 with a million or so iterations.

Comment: @zaph, i completely agree. however, this is just a school project.

Comment: Ah, that is even better, schools teaching to use MD5, even more exploits coming up.

Comment: Give it to 'em, @zaph! Complacency and Optimism are two of the seven deadly sins of the "programming is an art" philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. In the latest version of Xcode, apparently it does not look in the /usr/include/. I even tried to add this to the User header search path, but that ended up throwing more errors.

So I had to manually copy into Xcode's own internal usr directory:

/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include

After copying over the openssl folder, relaunched xcode and the error went away. I dont know why apple decided to move the Developer's folder within the app itself or why it doesnt just look in the /usr/ folder like gcc/g++ does, but this is a workaround that works for me now.

Comment: hi, I m trying to solve same issue. from where can I find openssl folder. I installed new hardDisk. So everything is fresh installed. In earlier hard disk I had xcode7.2. But it worked there. Now I am having this issue with fresh checkout.

Comment: So the way i solved it was i copied the files from `/usr/include/` and went into the application package and copied into the `usr` directory in their. If you have el capitan installed you have to download the latest from apple's developer's website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Xcode Command line tools from here for your exact Xcode version:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Then, openssl source will be installed in /usr/include.

Also, you need to link with openssl by adding "-lcrypto" and "-lssl" (if you need SSL too) in your linker's flags

Comment: Like I mentioned before I have installed the developers tool and verified that /usr/include/ directory was present. I did not know i had to pass those linker flags thank you for that.

Comment: Actually, you did not say you had installed the "Command line tools" package (but I deduced you did because you have openssl headers in /usr/include/). I started with this point in my answer for the other developers that might get the same message about one of the openssl header missing.

Comment: Where to add this flags. I tried in other linker flag. But did not work.